# Referencing a div (by id) that has been append()ed into the content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div I'm creating dynamically, with a unique id. I append() that to an area on the page.

Later, I try to reference that via $( '#id_here' ), but it returns nothing. Inspector in safari/chrome shows the existence and proper id of the element.

```
<script>
$( '#box' ).append( '<div><input id="id123" /></div>' );
//Later on in time...

function doingStuff(){
  alert( $( '#id123' ) );//undefined
}
</script>

<div id="box">

</div>
```

Comment: it works: http://jsbin.com/ajihe/edit (click preview)

Comment: We need more info. You stated that the element is successfully added to the page. It then should be accessible. There's something missing here.

Comment: Also, the `alert( $( '#id123' ) );` should never show `undefined`, even if no element is found.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you append the object not before the DOM is ready, otherwise you will probably not able to access #box yet.

```
$( document ).ready( function() 
{
    $( '#box' ).append( '<div><input id="id123" /></div>' );
} );
```

Comment: The question stated that the element is successfully added to the page, so it shouldn't be a DOM ready issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, it's just your alert statement that might be a bit off.  Currently, your passing the jquery result to the alert(), which just reports "[object Objerct]" (in Chrome anyway.  It'll differ for each browser).

Try:

```
alert($("#id123").val());
```

That would alert the value in the text box.

or

```
alert($("#id123")[0].id);
```

That would alert the id of the input (id123).

Perhaps you have an error elsewhere in your code?  What you've posted works fine.

**UPDATE**

As others have pointed out (and I missed), your script is running before the div is appended to the document, hence the "undefined".  Preventing your script from running by wrapping everything in:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Script here
});
```

is the way to go.

Comment: Or use `$("#id123").length` to see how many elements jQuery found, which is 0 in my firefox case :)

Comment: A `$(selector)` will never return `undefined`. Doesn't matter if the DOM is loaded or not, it will always return a jQuery object (albeit an empty one).

Answer (score 0):

Tell jQuery to wait for the [document to be ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29) before appending the div. This way, the document (and `#box`) is loaded and ready to be used before jQuery starts with its work. You do this by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '#box' ).append( '<div><input id="id123" /></div>' );
});
```

You can keep the rest of the code as it is

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've used to get arround that type of problems is to use .live() from Jquery, which attaches a handler to the desired event to be used on existent elements or elements to be created later on (like .append())...

**Ex.:**

```
$('#box').append('<div><input id="id123" /></div>');

$('#id123').live('click', function() {
  // Your Desired Code for that ID
});
```

Read more about this at: [Jquery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Assuming that your question is accurate, your element is created and in the referred browsers, it shows up nicely, so... having a .live() on page load for example, you can assign code to be executed for that particular ID that will be created on due time!! (or perhaps I misread your question and ask you some clarification) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Comments on my poorly hacked together and un-tested example were all fair.

Turns out my problem was a special character in my div id.

It's been a long day.

Comment: I was going to upvote you, but I didn't want to ruin your rep. \m/ ;-)